# How to add two numbers on same line?

Tags: android, kotlin, calculator

I want to add first and second value of editText. For example: If user enters 15 then add 1 into 5. I have tried this code:

```
    val input = editText.text
    if (input.length == 2) { 
        val firstValue = input.length == 1 
        val secondValue = input.length == 2 
        val result = firstValue + secondValue
        textView.text = result
    }
```

but I get this result: "[Ljava.lang.Boolean;@312b186"

Comment: what would `input.length == 1` indicate?

Comment: if you have a line of `if (input.length == 2)` which returns a boolean, why would `input.length == 1` therefore return the first input?

Comment: this question is in kotlin.

Comment: Honestly: I think you are trying to do 10 things at the same time, but you understand only 10% of the code you write. I think you are overburdening yourself right now, and you should step back and study some basic kotlin for a while. There is no point in trying to do "real world" things when you have no idea how the language works. Beyond that, you got some good answers by now, so please dont forget about accepting one of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are incorrectly retrieving the values from the EditText:

```
val firstValue = input.length == 1
```

What this will do is check if `input.length` has a length of 1, and will set `firstValue` to the resulting boolean (either `true` or `false`). hence why you are a Boolean as a result.

To retrieve text from an EditText, you must do something like:

```
val inputString = input.getText().toString()
```

Which will retrieve the text from an EditText as a String.

Next, we retrieve a single character using substring, then parse it to an integer.

```
val firstValue = inputString.substring(0,1).toInt()
val secondValue = inputString.subString(1,2).toInt()
```

We can now add our integers together to get the result:

```
val result = firstValue + secondValue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    val firstValue = input.length == 1 
    val secondValue = input.length == 2
```

Both of these blocks are actually booleans. firstValue is the boolean result of "is input length equal to 1", and similarly for secondValue. This means firstValue + secondValue is actually something like

```
val result = true + false
```

which I guess isn't being picked up as an error at compile time because of the Java 9 `val` keyword. But result is actually a boolean.

Comment: So what can i do to get firstValue and secondValue.

Comment: @user10646020 What do you **want** them to be? You see, `input.length == 1 ` results in a boolean value. Do you want true, or "true" as string?!

Comment: I tries to get 1st and 2nd values of user input and then add them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is "half of" a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4). But it goes beyond that.

The problem here is that val is hiding actual types, and then things go wrong.

`[Ljava.lang.Boolean;@312b186"` means that you are calling `toString()` on an array of **Boolean** objects.

In other words: instead of putting together a string object, you created a boolean array (with two values), and then you get thatArray.toString() as result.

So, in a first step: don't use `val` all over the place, but give distinct types.

It looks like you expect the **incoming** strings to be numbers. If so, you should rather do as the other answer suggests, and use `toInt()` on your input strings!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `val firstValue = input.length == 1` returns a boolean. As is somewhat clear by the original `if` test.

To get the value of the position, first you will need to do something like:

```
val firstValue = input.get(0);
```

However, I would expect that to return a `String`. So you will need to convert the `String` to an integer.

```
val firstValue = input.get(0).toInt(10);
```

You should then be able to add the values (subject to making modifications to the `secondValue`).

Note: instead of `get()`, it might be necessary to do `.subSequence(0, 1)` and `.subsequence(1, 2)` depending upon the specifics of the `.toInt()`. I don't have a Kotlin environment running at the moment to confirm.

Comment: Ah, I was about to change my answer to talk about "how to convert to int". I took the short path, just mention it, and upvoted your example instead ;-)

Comment: You're right about having to use `subsequence`, `toInt` on a CharSequence won't compile. Another small note, semicolons are optional

Answer (score 1):

firstValue and secondValue are assigned booleans and not Ints. A quick fix will be as follows.

```
val input = editText.text.toString()
if (input.length == 2) { 
    val firstValue = input[0]
    val secondValue = input[1]
    val result = firstValue.toInt() + secondValue.toInt()
    textView.text = "$result"
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the remainder of the number by using modulus operation and add the remainder to the result variable. Here's the code...

```
    int remainder, result = 0;
    String value= editText.getText().toString();
    int i=Integer.parseInt(value);
    int temp=i;
    while(temp != 0){
        remainder=temp % 10;
        result += remainder;
        temp=temp/10;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the issue of the OP. They have (in essence) a `String`, and this answer starts with the assumption of an `int`. If the OP first converted the `String` to an `int`, then this approach could work.

Comment: The question is asking for Kotlin, this won't compile

Comment: @KevinO You're right. I just gave him the logic of how to do it. Obviously for his requirement, editText content should be converted to int. I probably should've mentioned that in the answer.